# AJAX/jQuery generated inputs not recognized by other jQuery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

I have what I assume is a relatively simple issue. For testing purposes I have made it so simple so as to locate the issue.

I have a jQuery script that works alongside AJAX to return some results next to checkboxes, here it is below:

```
$.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: '/customers/details/emails',
            dataType:'json',
            data: {
                'customerID': $('select[name=payer_id]').val(),
               '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');

                    if ((data.errors)) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#createOrigin').modal('show');
                            toastr.error('Check your inputs!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                        }, 500);

                        if (data.errors.title) {
                            $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
                        }
                        if (data.errors.content) {
                            $('.errorContent').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorContent').text(data.errors.content);
                        }
                    } else {
                         $.each(data, function(i,val) {
                                    $('<tr>').append(
                                    $('<td>').html('<input type="checkbox" id="emailCheckboxSelect">'),
                                    $('<td>').text(val)).appendTo('#customerEmails');

               });
              }
             }
            });
```

As you can see near the end, for each result a table row is appended, with a checkbox with an id of "emailCheckboxSelect".

Now to my problem, these are obviously dynamically created elements so I believe this is the issue with this script (a simple dummy just to locate the issue). Here is that script that should work:

```
$(function(){
    $('#emailCheckboxSelect').click(function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

This doesn't work with the dynamically created elements. However, I did add `<input type="checkbox" id="emailCheckboxSelect">Checkbox` directly to my page, and this does set off the alert.

So what am I doing wrong and what do I need to do so that jQuery can recognize dynamically created elements?

Comment: $.each(data, function(i,val) {
                                    $('<tr>').append(
                                    $('<td>').html('<input type="checkbox" id="emailCheckboxSelect">'),
                                    $('<td>').text(val)).appendTo('#customerEmails');

               });

Comment: @GordonKushner - it's close to the bottom right after the }else{ in the first script

Comment: Ids need to be unique, so you need to generate separate ids. M. Gara answer is right, but you need to correct the ids too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try to bind the click event after the $.each(data, function() {}) inside the sucess: function() {}
2. You are using multiple elements with same id in the DOM : Element IDs should be unique within the entire document.
3. use classes instead

your code will look like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/customers/details/emails',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'customerID': $('select[name=payer_id]').val(),
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
        $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');

        if ((data.errors)) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#createOrigin').modal('show');
                toastr.error('Check your inputs!', 'Error Alert', {
                    timeOut: 5000
                });
            }, 500);

            if (data.errors.title) {
                $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
                $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
            }
            if (data.errors.content) {
                $('.errorContent').removeClass('hidden');
                $('.errorContent').text(data.errors.content);
            }
        } else {
            $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                $('<tr>').append(
                    $('<td>').html('<input type="checkbox" class="emailCheckboxSelect" />'),
                    $('<td>').text(val)).appendTo('#customerEmails');

            });
            $('.emailCheckboxSelect').click(function(e) {
                alert('clicked');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: YES!! Thank you so very much for the help (and yes I understand about the IDs, at the time I copied this to my question, I was just trying anything). Thank you thank you thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `click` event to something like

```
$('td').on('click', '.emailCheckboxSelect', function () {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

This would work on dynamically created elements. Also, use class instead of id for dynamically created elements.